# ionic-framework suddenly went blank

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

can anyone help me? 
i just learn ionic. it work well when i use ionic serve yesterday,
 then it suddenly display blank page today. i am not changing anything in my code . 
here my code for routing. thanks

app.js

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ngcordova'])
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  })
 })

.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
  $stateProvider
     .state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
    })
 .state('faculty', {
    url: '/faculty',
    templateUrl: 'templates/faculty.html'
    })
    .state('calender', {
     url: '/calender',
      templateUrl: 'templates/calender.html'
    })   
  ;
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
})
```

Comment: Can you use the inspect element console to see what is the error you are having?

Comment: yes you need to inspect and show us error. "Right Click" On browser page and select "inspect" then Select "Console" OR run "ionic serve -c" in command prompt, this will show you error in command prompt

Comment: thanks @DrenP, i've solved the problem. i remove ngCordova, then it works :-)